# Writing LKM for a Device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am looking for some tutorials where writing LKM for some specific device has been taught.I learned basic of writing LKM but wanted to see how to write LKM for some device(fpga device or Network device). I know for writing LKM for device one need to know characteristics of a device.

But what could be characteristics of an FPGA device or Network device and how access them through LKM.

So,can anyone let me know what all are required to write a LKM for device?

Comment: I am not sure if you could find a comprehensive guide detailing for each and every kind of device out there. But most books on drivers covers the major categories of devices.

Nevertheless would like to point out that network devices are not like any other device in the kernel. There are no file operations per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically to start learning to write Linux kernel networking drivers,
the following 2 tutorials should get you started.

1. [**Simple network driver for Realtek 8139**](http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html)
2. [**Network driver for AT91SAM9263  from scratch**](http://free-electrons.com/doc/network-drivers-lab.pdf)